# Go's kafka library watermill and multiple subscribers

Tags: go, apache-kafka

After long search I've found kafka library which is simple enough I can understand it. :)
https://github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/watermill/blob/master/_examples/pubsubs/kafka/main.go

My question is how can I create multiple subscribers to read from specific topic?
I've tried to modify above example with

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/IBM/sarama"
    "github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/watermill"
    "github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/watermill-kafka/v2/pkg/kafka"
    "github.com/ThreeDotsLabs/watermill/message"
)

func main() {
    saramaSubConfig := kafka.DefaultSaramaSubscriberConfig()
    saramaSubConfig.Consumer.Offsets.Initial = sarama.OffsetOldest
    brokers := []string{"127.0.0.1:9092", "127.0.0.1:9093"}
    subscriber, err := kafka.NewSubscriber(kafka.SubscriberConfig{
        Brokers:               brokers,
        Unmarshaler:           kafka.DefaultMarshaler{},
        OverwriteSaramaConfig: saramaSubConfig,
        ConsumerGroup:         "TestGroup",
    },
        watermill.NewStdLogger(false, false),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    messages, err := subscriber.Subscribe(context.Background(), "test")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go process(messages, "one")
    messages2, err := subscriber.Subscribe(context.Background(), "test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go process(messages2, "two")

    pubisher, err := kafka.NewPublisher(kafka.PublisherConfig{
        Brokers:   brokers,
        Marshaler: kafka.DefaultMarshaler{},
    }, watermill.NewStdLogger(false, false),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    publishMessage(pubisher)

}

func publishMessage(publisher message.Publisher) {
    counter := 0
    for {
        msg := message.NewMessage(watermill.NewUUID(), []byte(fmt.Sprintf("Hello world %d", counter)))
        if err := publisher.Publish("test", msg); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        counter++
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func process(messages <-chan *message.Message, goroutineId string) {
    for msg := range messages {
        log.Printf("goroutine %s recived message: %s, payload: %s", goroutineId, msg.UUID, string(msg.Payload))
        msg.Ack()
    }
}
```

but it seems that only go routine which receives "two" always process the message.

Answer (score 1):

You have two consumers in the same consumer group.

If you only have one partition for your test topic, then there can only be one active consumer in the group.

To have both consumers working on the same events, you'll need to create subscribers with unique groups

Answer (score 0):

I have two partitions.

```
Topic: test2    TopicId: GEmDDeZ5QwerCsY-oRsi3w PartitionCount: 2       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs:
        Topic: test2    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: test2    Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
```

> Kafka assigns the partitions of a topic to the consumer in a consumer group, so that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the consumer group. Kafka guarantees that a message is only ever read by a single consumer in the consumer group.

https://medium.com/javarevisited/kafka-partitions-and-consumer-groups-in-6-mins-9e0e336c6c00

Isn't that the whole idea to increase throughput when you have multiple consumers on consumer group so they could read data from topic?

edit:

I think I know where is the issue.
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

> Events with the same event key (e.g., a customer or vehicle ID) are written to the same partition,

so why this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/IBM/sarama"
)

const (
    topic = "test2"
)

func main() {
    brokers := []string{"localhost:9092", "localhost:9093"}
    cfg := sarama.NewConfig()
    cfg.Producer.Return.Successes = true

    producer, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(brokers, cfg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    counter := 0
    for {
        msg := sarama.ProducerMessage{
            Topic:     topic,
            Partition: -1,
            Value:     sarama.StringEncoder(fmt.Sprintf("Hello world %d", counter)),
        }
        if counter%2 == 0 {
            msg.Key = sarama.StringEncoder("two")
        } else {
            msg.Key = sarama.StringEncoder("one")
        }

        partition, offset, err := producer.SendMessage(&msg)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print("Failed to sent message", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Sent message to partiotion %d with offset %d key %s", partition, offset, msg.Key)
        counter++
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    }

}
```

sends all events to the same partition?:

```
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7882 key two
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7883 key one
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7884 key two
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7885 key one
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7886 key two
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7887 key one
2023/08/21 09:04:37 Sent message to partiotion 1 with offset 7888 key two
```

Isn't it this field:

```
if counter%2 == 0 {
            msg.Key = sarama.StringEncoder("two")
        } else {
            msg.Key = sarama.StringEncoder("one")
        }
```

responsible for event key?

edit 2: :)
Nevermind! It works correctly, I've misunderstood one concept. :)